# Genymotion crash after start it

Tags: android, genymotion

After I start it will close immediately and show this log on terminal:

> player:
>   ../../../../../../../src/mesa/drivers/dri/i915/i915_fragprog.c:1273:
>   i915BindProgram: Assertion `p->on_hardware == 0' failed.

I think it due to mesa version: This is my OpenGL and Mesa version

> OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to Uncheck the "Use Host GPU" checkbox - in the emulator settings

Comment: I cannot find it with Genymotion.

Comment: It's a genymotion not a emulator of android studio

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy try to update latest version of `Mesa`.

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy if you are using `Tablet` . try to change it `Galaxy Note`.

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy here is discussion about that bug. https://disqus.com/home/discussion/4teq/run_clash_of_clans_on_ubuntu_linux_windows/